# Auto increment inside a loop

Tags: php

I need to auto increment an array value inside a `while` loop. If the array value is `$Values[2]`, I need it to be `$Values[3]` on the next loop. What I have is not providing any results.

```
//select the top spread winners
$query_moline = "SELECT * FROM `highscore_leader` WHERE `game_id`=\"$game_id\" AND `leader_id`<>\"$curmemid\" AND `score`>\"$myscore\" AND `active`='Y' ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT \"$top_payout\"";
$moline = mysql_query($query_moline) or die(mysql_error());
$row_moline = mysql_fetch_assoc($moline);
$totalRows_moline = mysql_num_rows($moline);

$index=$top_payout;
static $i=2;

do {

$score_id=$row_moline['id'];
$player_id=$row_moline['leader_id'];

if($totalRows_moline>0){
foreach ($row_moline['id'] as $scoreid)
     {
        $i++;
     }
$player_comission=$values[$i];
//update payout tables
$strsql="UPDATE `ttourmember` SET `accountamount`=(`accountamount`+\"$player_comission\") WHERE `memberid`=\"$player_id\"";
mysql_query($strsql,$connect) or die(mysql_error());
$chkrow3=mysql_affected_rows($connect); 

}} while ($row_moline = mysql_fetch_assoc($moline));
```

Comment: Why not increment $i for values in a for each loop?

Comment: `foreach ($row_moline['id'] as $scoreid)` doesn't make sense. A column returned from a mysql query cannot be an array. Doesn't this get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//select the top spread winners

$query_moline = "SELECT * FROM `highscore_leader` WHERE `game_id`=\"$game_id\" AND `leader_id`<>\"$curmemid\" AND `score`>\"$myscore\" AND `active`='Y' ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT \"$top_payout\"";
$moline = mysql_query($query_moline) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_moline = mysql_num_rows($moline);

$index=$top_payout;
static $i=2;
$i = 0;

if($totalRows_moline>0)
{
    while($row_moline = mysql_fetch_assoc($moline)) 
    {    
        $score_id=$row_moline['id'];
        $player_id=$row_moline['leader_id'];

        $player_comission=$values[$i];
        //update payout tables
        $strsql="UPDATE `ttourmember` SET `accountamount`=  (`accountamount`+\"$player_comission\") WHERE `memberid`=\"$player_id\"";
        mysql_query($strsql,$connect) or die(mysql_error());
        $chkrow3=mysql_affected_rows($connect); 
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Sorry about the formatting.. On the phone! Could someone please fix!